# Pyplot directly on yfinance object is fast. Pyplot on equivalent csv is slow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yfinance

## Pyplot directly on data from yfinance

Here's a little script which loads data into pyplot from yfinance:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = yf.Ticker('MSFT').history(period="max").reset_index()[["Date", "Open"]]

plt.plot(data["Date"], data["Open"])

plt.show()
```

The UI loads quickly and is quite responsive. It looks like this:

[image]

## Pyplot on equivalent data from csv

Here's a similar script which writes the data to CSV, loads it from CSV, then plots the graph using the data from CSV:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = yf.Ticker('MSFT').history(period="max").reset_index()[["Date", "Open"]]

data.to_csv('out.csv')

from_csv = pd.read_csv('out.csv', index_col=0)

plt.plot(from_csv["Date"], from_csv["Open"])

plt.show()
```

This time:

- The UI loads much more slowly
- Zooming is slow
- Panning is slow
- Resizing is slow
- The horizontal axes labels don't display clearly

## Question

I'd like to avoid hitting the yfinance API each time the script is run so as to not burden their systems unnecessarily. (I'd include a bit more logic than in the script above which takes care of not accessing the API if a CSV is available. I kept the example simple for the sake of demonstration.)

Is there a way to get the CSV version to result in a pyplot UI that is as responsive as the direct-from-API version?

Comment: After getting the data, I save it to CSV, and the saved CSV file is not slow to load, but the graph drawing is slow. The only way to draw it is to thin out the data.

Comment: @r-beginners I was able to resolve the issue. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

When loading from CSV, the `Date` column needs to be converted to an actual date value.

```
from_csv["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(from_csv["Date"])
```

Here's a fast version of the above script:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = yf.Ticker('MSFT').history(period="max").reset_index()[["Date", "Open"]]

data.to_csv('out.csv')

from_csv = pd.read_csv('out.csv', index_col=0)

from_csv["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(from_csv["Date"])

plt.plot(from_csv["Date"], from_csv["Open"])

plt.show()
```